# Why doesn't charcoal sound like "Karcoal"?

Tags: pronunciation, history

Well, I wanna know why this word doesn't sound like "K".

You know, `character` sounds like "karacter" with "K" but... what about `charcoal`??

Thanks!!

Comment: Because English spelling was designed 500 years ago and never upgraded from beta. So it doesn't represent modern English pronunciation. You hafta learn how to say each word **as well as** how to spell it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Basically, "character" is out of character.

Comment: Middle English: from Old French caractere, via Latin from Greek kharaktēr -- No telling why the "h" got introduced into the word.

Comment: Why don't **chat, chair, change** etc. pronounced with K?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the word "character" comes from Greek, and in words that come from Greek, "ch" is usually pronounced like "k".

According to Douglas Harper's Online Etymology Dictionary, [the origin of the word "charcoal"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/charcoal#etymonline_v_8436) is not known with certainty; he says it comes either from Old French or Old English. In any case, "charcoal" certainly doesn't come from Greek, so it's not pronounced like it is in words of Greek origin. It simply uses the usual pronunciation of "ch".

Comment: very interesting

Comment: Thanks very much!!